# Deleting migrate module tables post migration

Tags: database, migrations

We did a *massive* migration a while back, several hundred thousand rows. Needless to say we now have a bunch of migrate tables that we could do without.

I've disabled the migrate modules but before I dropped the tables (or should I truncate?) I wanted to make doubly sure that this will have no affect on anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I deleted the tables (actually truncated them) on my dev server and there have been no side effects that I have noticed, so will try deleting the tables in their entirely. The migrate tables made up around 600mb in a dump.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's usefull to keep the migrate tables while you are working on migration, in case you need to see the mapping and revert/redoing stuff.

But actually I was having some troubling while using the migrate module for other pursings. This SQL error: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory` did keeping show up when I did try to use drush migrate:... till delete those tables.

With this query you can delete all table with prefix `migrate`

```
SET GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN=10000;
SET @tbls = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE_NAME)
               FROM information_schema.TABLES
              WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db'
                AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'migrate\%');
SET @delStmt = CONCAT('DROP TABLE ',  @tbls);
-- SELECT @delStmt;
PREPARE stmt FROM @delStmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```